# How to run 'lm' function in R, but with a formula with only an intercept?

Tags: r, regression

I've tried running a formula similar to `y ~ 1`. This gives me just an intercept, but is the value that's shown equal to intercept estimate(without covariates) + 1, or just intercept estimate(without covariates)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Won't the intercept just be mean(y)

Comment: Since the formula references only `y` and the constant `1`, *how could it possibly even know about any covariates?*

Comment: @whuber I do not know. In R if you put -1, then lm does a regression without a constant. By putting just a 1, we could activate another option, unknown to me... That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Option or not, if you don't supply any covariates to a procedure, there isn't any way for it to use them, is there?

Comment: @whuber you're probably right, even though I could say that lm(formula, data), and in data the lm function could find the covariates...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you do linear regression on only a constant, you will only get the intercept value, which is really just the mean of the outcome.

In R we have:

```
y <- rnorm(1000)
lm(y ~ 1)
# intercept = 0.00965
mean(y)
# Equal to 0.00965
```

The reason for doing it the regression way, rather than just computing the mean, is to get an easy standard error.

If have no idea what you mean with "intercept +1", but what you do get is the mean of the outcome, i.e. the expected value of y when you do not control for anything.

Comment: Thanks Repmat.

Also, another reason for doing this, is that some packages require the user to define a base model, e.g. 'BayesVarSel'.